# With css want to show some content before div

Tags: html, css

Here https://jsfiddle.net/pzdcjtfo/38/ is whole example.

Initial code is this:

```css
.append_section {position: relative;}

    .append_section::before {
    content:'Before';
    background:white;
    color:green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    }


    .resizable_div { 
    resize:both;
    overflow:auto;
    }

    div{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:250px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="resizable_div append_section" contenteditable>
Some text before which i want to show some element or content <br/>
</div>
```

I want to show content before `.append_section`. But it shows nothing. If i remove `overflow:auto;` and inside `.append_section` insert some element (`div`, `span`), then all works.

But i need to keep div resizable and do not want to insert any elements inside `.append_section`.

Can anyone advice how to get all this to work.

**Edit** Thanks to @Temani Afif corrected and all works.

Comment: typo error ... remove the space before `::before`